# How to read data from a decrypted string

Tags: php

```
string(284) "a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"01a046827a00cf838a1b3ce585cc82fb";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"124.43.56.156";s:10:"user_agent";s:120:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";s:13:"last_activity";i:1371099813;}"
```

This is a decrypted cookie from CodeIgniter. I need to access data from this. Preferably convert to an array or something which is easily accessible like `data -> session_id`. Which would be the possible way to extract data from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) it.

```
var_dump( unserialize('a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"01a046827a00cf838a1b3ce585cc82fb";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"124.43.56.156";s:10:"user_agent";s:120:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";s:13:"last_activity";i:1371099813;}'));
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

That's a serialized string, just call [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$array = unserialize($string);
```

and you have it back as array:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 01a046827a00cf838a1b3ce585cc82fb
    [ip_address] => 124.43.56.156
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
    [last_activity] => 1371099813
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its a serialized array. Use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and get it to variable.

```
$arr = unserialize($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unserialize to convert the serialize string into array

```
   $arr = unserialize($string);

   print_r($arr) //will display you the array values
```